# jquery file upload not triggering click in dynamically generated input

Tags: javascript, jquery

I am dynamically generating input divs and then trying to import the images to the div but the file upload is not working.
I have a image button for a file upload instead of choose files.

```
(function() {
    var fileTriggers = $('.js_file_emit');
    $('#row_container').on('click', '.js_file_emit', function() {
        debugger;
        console.log($(this).attr('data-file'));
        $($(this).attr('data-file')).live('click', function(e) {
            $('#' + $(this).attr('data-file')).on('change', function() {
                handleFiles($(this).files, $(this).attr('data-preview'));
            });
        })
    })
})();
```

the code is working if I have predefined inputs. http://jsfiddle.net/xnf0bht7/9/

This is how I am generating my div

```
function updatePopupRows(data) {
    var l_sRowContainer = "#row_container",
        l_sNameTemp = null,
        l_sRowTemp = null,
        l_sRowHeader = null,
        l_sImgTemp = null,
        l_sFileTemp = null,
        l_sPrevTemp = null;

    $(l_sRowContainer).html('');

    for (var i = 0; i < data.data.length; i++) {
        l_sRowTemp = document.createElement('div');
        $(l_sRowTemp).attr('class', 'row');

        l_sRowHeader = document.createElement('div');
        $(l_sRowHeader).attr('class', 'row_header_fancybox');

        l_sNameTemp = document.createElement('span');
        $(l_sNameTemp).html(data.data[i].name);

        l_sImgTemp = document.createElement('input');
        $(l_sImgTemp).attr('type', 'image').attr('class', 'js_file_emit').attr('id', 'js_file_emit').attr('src', '/toogle/resources/js/slickgrid/add.png').attr('data-file', 'group' + data.data[i].name + i);

        l_sFileTemp = document.createElement('input');
        $(l_sFileTemp).attr('type', 'file').attr('multiple', 'true').attr('id', "group" + data.data[i].name + i).attr('data-preview', 'preview' + data.data[i].name + i);

        l_sPrevTemp = document.createElement('div');
        $(l_sPrevTemp).attr('id', 'preview' + data.data[i].name + i);

        $(l_sRowHeader).append(l_sNameTemp).append(l_sImgTemp).append(l_sFileTemp).append(l_sPrevTemp);
        $(l_sRowTemp).append(l_sRowHeader);
        $(l_sRowContainer).append(l_sRowTemp);
    }
}
```

HTML:

```
 <div id='row_container'></div>
```

Comment: Is `row_container` div generated dynamically ?

Comment: then you can't use `$('#row_container').on('click',...` because jquery won't see it, give me a minute to write an answer

Comment: no row container is there. its not dynamically generated

Comment: oh it's there? so your code is correct, it should work

Comment: yes it should work. It is working in the fiddle but when I am generating the inputs dynamically its not opening the fileuploader popup

Comment: can you please make a jsfiddle for the problem (the dynamically generated inputs) ?

Comment: The data is coming from the backend so it will not be possible to make a fiddle for the dynamically added inputs. I have added code how I am generating teh inputs

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/80114/discussion-between-fadi-obaji-and-psdebugger).

Answer (score -1):

All click listeners should use the .on('click','selector',function(){}) syntax (you use the deprecated "live" method in your nested click). The click listeners can be loaded when the page loads. Anytime you add an element, also assign it the class that you use to set the click listeners.

You must include the preventDefault() call to keep the child click from bubbling up and firing the parent action. Here is an example of dynamically created elements with click listeners:

http://jsfiddle.net/iaretyler/qwn0a8k4/

Notice I have the click listener on the page already, I just create the element with the appropriate class. The same should be done with the "change" listener

You should also check out creating new elements with jQuery. It simplifies the creation a bit. You can change this:

```
l_sRowTemp =document.createElement('div');
$(l_sRowTemp).attr('class','row');
```

to this (notice the attributes go in the second param:

```
var l_sRowTemp = $('<div>', {class: "row"});
//Now append to whatever
```

Comment: no this is not working. It is going into this function but doesnt open the file uploader popup

Comment: Updated to provide example of dynamic child clicks.